# Simple autoloader, but trying to make it psr-compliat

Tags: php, object-oriented

I made this class, just to understand what PSR autloader is. I didn't want to download and use it without knowing how it works. So, the one I built is very simple, but I would like a review on how to improve it, and what it lacks to be 100% psr-1 compliant.

Here is the class loader.

```
namespace ClassLoader; 

class Loader
{
    private $classDir; 
    private $namespace; 
    public $dirSeparatorSymbol = '\\'; 

    public function __construct($namespace, $classDir)
    {
        $this->classDir = $classDir; 
        $this->namespace = $namespace;

    }

    private function load($class)
    {

        $include_path = str_replace($this->dirSeparatorSymbol, DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $this->classDir);

        $classFilename = substr($class, strrpos($class, '\\') + 1) . '.php';

        if(file_exists($class = $include_path.$classFilename)){
            require $class;

            return true; 
        }



    }   

    public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register([$this, 'load']);
    }
}
```

Also: You can see the constructor's first argument: `__construct($namespace, ...` has a namespace param. But I don't know how this is used. The class loads any functions just by doing:

```
$a = new ClassLoader\Loader('unused/param', 'path/to/bar');
$a->register(); 

new bar;
```

Comment: You're using a string as a directory separator. PHP defines a cross-platform directory separator in a predefined constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`. So, your `public $dirSeparatorSymbol` can be completely removed.

Comment: ok, that's one valuable insight. Anything more? @jsanc623

Comment: you $classFilename sthingy could be rewritten using strrchr: $classFilename = substr(strrchr($class,'\\'),1) . '.php';

Comment: @Pinoniq Thanks. I notice that now. But do you have any inputs as to how it I can make it psr-compliant?

Comment: You might also want to look into composer. This way you can handle psr-0, psr-4 and even non psr class loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your class is psr-1 compliant. But i think you mean psr-0.

To have a maximum compliance to the psr-0 autoloader. simply copy paste it...

Your method for instance doesn't work for Class_Name

if you call your autoload with \namespace\ClassName the first \ doesn't get trimmed. This will leed to problems. (php will load /path/to/lib//namespace/ClassName.php)

as mentioned in the comments, the use of the $this->dirSeparatorSymbol is weird. You don't need it. so don't use it.

### Edit: 'unused' namespace

Often you will have multiple libraries at different places. Your own will probably reside under `ROOT.'/lib/'` but other libraries you downloaded should/will be under `ROOT.'/vendor/AwesomeLibrary/src/'`. to accomodate this. You will register 2 autoloaders:

$personalLoader = new ClassLoader\Loader('Personal','/lib/');
$personalLoader->register();

$awesomeLoader = new ClassLoader\Loader('AwesomeLibrary','/vendor/AwesomeLibrary/src/');
$awesomeLoader->register();

Now your autoloader should check or it is allowed to load the file. For instance if I `use
AwesomeLibrary/MyClass;` the personal loader shouldn't do anything since it knows nothing about AwesomeLibrary. the second awesomeLoader however knows how to load the AwesomeLibrary.

Comment: Thanks for finally helping out. Assuming PSR-1 is 'advanced' than PSR-0 I have no reason to make it PSR-0 compliant if, it already fits PSR-1 standards. The only reason, I asked for PSR-0, is because I wanted to start from easier version. So, assume I am talking about PSR-1, I still don't understand what to make of the first argument for the `Loader()` class. It seems, that is reserved for entering the namespace, but the class already loads namespaced classes without the use of this first argument. So, what I am doing wrong? In simple terms, how should I make use of the first argument?

Comment: psr-1 is about coding standards. psr-0 is about autoloading. the advanced autoloading is psr-4 ...

Comment: I guess that is the problem. I thought all was about autoloading. I tried to look at the outoloader, but for me they were a little complicated. Which is why I wanted to make mine and compare it just to see if I have what it takes to build my own autoloader